# Android to PHP not working

Tags: java, php, android, http-post

I'm really stuck on this, I'm trying to send post data from android activity to PHP file and my code is just not working. The application just stops as soon as it opens. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a pointer as to what to fix or if you could edit the code and post an example, thanks so much.
here is my code-

```
package com.xavware.httptest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void go(View v) {
        check();
    }

    private boolean check() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes There is Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return info != null && info.isConnected();
    }

    public void sendPostRequest(View v){
        new PostClass(this).execute();
    }

    private class PostClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        private final Context context;

        public PostClass(Context c){
            this.context = c;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params){
            try{
                URL url = new URL("http://a.argueit.uk/dm/postdata.php");

                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                String data = "xav";
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
                con.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,un;0.5");
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                dStream.writeBytes(data);
                dStream.flush();
                dStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            }catch(MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }




}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
**03-15 16:21:37.385 16458-16458/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-15 16:21:37.471 16458-16458/com.mhealth.healthnotation W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.mhealth.healthnotation-1/lib/arm
03-15 16:21:37.590 16458-16485/com.mhealth.healthnotation D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-15 16:21:37.653 16458-16485/com.mhealth.healthnotation I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (I14a17c7611)
                                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.02
                                                                        Build Date: 12/04/15 Fri
                                                                        Local Branch: workspace
                                                                        Remote Branch: 
                                                                        Local Patches: 
                                                                        Reconstruct Branch: 
03-15 16:21:37.655 16458-16485/com.mhealth.healthnotation I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-15 16:21:41.220 16458-16718/com.mhealth.healthnotation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                            Process: com.mhealth.healthnotation, PID: 16458
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                                                at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:345)
                                                                                at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
                                                                                at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
                                                                                at com.xavware.httptest.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:95)
                                                                                at com.xavware.httptest.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
03-15 16:21:41.406 16458-16485/com.mhealth.healthnotation E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9a84920
03-15 16:21:41.407 16458-16485/com.mhealth.healthnotation D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb9a78780 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb9ad8270**
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat so we can see the error stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the problem but first make sure you actually added internet permission in the manifest file.

Here is an example for async task with POST method:

```
private class SendMessageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Graduate targetGraduate;

    public SendMessageTask(Graduate targetGraduate){
        this.targetGraduate = targetGraduate;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL myUrl = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        String response = "";
        String data = params[0];

        try {
            myUrl = new URL("http://your url");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //one long string, first encode is the key to get the  data on your web 
            //page, second encode is the value, keep concatenating key and value.
            //theres another ways which easier then this long string in case you are 
            //posting a lot of info, look it up.
            String postData = URLEncoder.encode("TOKEN", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(targetGraduate.getToken(), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("SENDER_ID", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(MainActivity.curretUser.getId(), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("MESSAGE_DATA", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(postData);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();

            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            os.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //do what ever you want with the response
        Log.d("roee", s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 2 did not work it returned the same error "could not run doInBackground" but thank you for the example it was very useful.

Comment: Good to know, I will edit my answer, you can keep searching because I know there is other ways without using this long string.